# Data access layer patterns using azure function

Tags: azure, design-patterns, azure-functions, data-access-layer

We are currently working on a design using Azure functions with Azure storage queue binding.
Each message in the queue represents a complete transaction. An Azure function will be bound to that queue so that the function will be triggered as soon as there is a new message in the queue.
The function will then commit the transaction in a SQL DB.

The first-cut implementation is also complete; and it's working fine. However, on retrospective, we are considering the following:
In a typical DAL, there are well-established design patterns using entity framework, repository patterns, etc. However, we didn't find a similar guidance/best practices when implementing DAL within a server-less code.
Therefore, my question is: should such patterns be implemented with Azure functions (this would be challenging :) ), or should the server-less code be kept as light as possible or this is not a use-case for azure functions, at all?

Comment: Why are familiar patterns hard to use? If you are using C# precompiled functions, you should be able to do that, with some nuance around configuration and versioning.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't take anything too special. We're using a routine set of library DLLs for all kinds of things -- database, interacting with other parts of Azure (like retrieving Key Vault secrets for connection strings), parsing file uploads, business rules, and so on. The libraries are targeting netstandard20 so we can more easily migrate to Functions v2 when the right triggers become available.

Mainly just design your libraries so they're highly modularized, so you can minimize how much you load to get the job done (assuming reuse in other areas of the system is important, which it usually is).

It would be easier if dependency injection was available today. See [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/299) for a few ways some of  us have hacked it together until we get official DI support. (DI is on the roadmap for Functions, I believe the 3.0 release.)

At first I was a little worried about startup time with the library approach, but the underlying WebJobs stack itself is already pretty heavy, and Functions startup performance seems to vary wildly anyway (on the cheaper tiers, at least). During testing, one of our infrequently-executed Functions has varied from just ~300ms to a peak of about ~3800ms to parse the exact same test file, with all but ~55ms spent on startup).

Answer (score 0):

> should such patterns be implemented with Azure functions (this would
>   be challenging :) ), or should the server-less code be kept as light
>   as possible or this is not a use-case for azure functions, at all?

My answer is NO.
There should be patterns to follow, but the traditional repository patterns and CRUD operations do not seem to be valid in the cloud era.
Many strong concepts we were raised up to adhere to, became invalid these days.
Denormalizing the data base became something not only acceptable but preferable.

Now designing a pattern will depend on the database you selected for your solution and also depends of the type of your application and the type of your data.

This is a link for general guideline when you do [Table Storage design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide).

Is your application read-heavy or write-heavy ? The design will vary accordingly.
Are you using Azure Tables or Mongo? There are design decisions based on that. Indexing is important in Mongo while there is non in Azure table that you can do.

Sharding consideration.
Redundancy Consideration.

In modern development/Architecture many principles has changed, each Microservice has its own database that might be totally different that any other Microservices'.

If you read along the guidelines that I provided, you will see what I mean.

**Designing your Table service solution to be read efficient:**

Design for querying in read-heavy applications. When you are designing your tables, think about the queries (especially the latency sensitive ones) that you will execute before you think about how you will update your entities. This typically results in an efficient and performant solution.
Specify both PartitionKey and RowKey in your queries. Point queries such as these are the most efficient table service queries.
**Consider storing duplicate copies of entities**. Table storage is cheap so consider storing the same entity multiple times (with different keys) to enable more efficient queries.
**Consider denormalizing your data.** Table storage is cheap so consider denormalizing your data. For example, store summary entities so that queries for aggregate data only need to access a single entity.
Use compound key values. The only keys you have are PartitionKey and RowKey. For example, use compound key values to enable alternate keyed access paths to entities.
Use query projection. You can reduce the amount of data that you transfer over the network by using queries that select just the fields you need.
Designing your Table service solution to be write efficient:

Do not create hot partitions. Choose keys that enable you to spread your requests across multiple partitions at any point of time.
Avoid spikes in traffic. Smooth the traffic over a reasonable period of time and avoid spikes in traffic.
Don't necessarily create a separate table for each type of entity. When you require atomic transactions across entity types, you can store these multiple entity types in the same partition in the same table.
Consider the maximum throughput you must achieve. You must be aware of the scalability targets for the Table service and ensure that your design will not cause you to exceed them.

Another good source is this [link](https://gauravmantri.com/2013/01/11/some-best-practices-for-building-windows-azure-cloud-applications/):